# Draw line inwards in Unity using Line Renderer

Tags: unity, 2d

Is there a way to draw the line inwards instead of from the center using Line Renderer in Unity?

Another option would be to move the Vector points inwards by half the width of the line, but If I have a complex polygon how do I do it uniformly?

[image]

EDIT: Found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109536/an-algorithm-for-inflating-deflating-offsetting-buffering-polygons which may be useful

Comment: What do you mean by inwards, the image to me looks like a line renderer without corner smoothing...

Comment: The default behavior of the line renderer is using the points Vector list as the center of the resulting line, I would like that the Vector points list are used as the border and draw the line inwards.